# Duplicate users in the same dates

Tags: sql

I have a list of users who had discounts.
I need to find users who has duplicate discounts in the same dates.
I was able to find the duplicate users on the list but I do not know how to check that the dates overlap.

How to solve this?

```
SELECT user, COUNT (*)
FROM discounts
GROUP BY user
HAVING COUNT (*) > 1
order by user
```

Comment: you can group by multiple columns: `SELECT user, COUNT () FROM discounts GROUP BY user,discountDate HAVING COUNT () > 1 `

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking SQL questions.

Answer (score 0):

You must add the date to the group by clause

Try this

```
SELECT user, your_date_column, COUNT (*)
FROM discounts
GROUP BY user, your_date_column
HAVING COUNT (*) > 1
order by user
```

Now, for each user per date if a user has two or more discounts will be in the result.
Pay attention that if your date column has time also you must convert it to date only. for example in SQL-Server use CAST(your_dateTime_column as DATE) in the group by clause.

Comment: @AvidanNisan Good luck